# how to delete using power shell " (quotes) in the variable if exist

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

how to remove double quotes (" ") if exist in the path using POWER SHELL

if example i have variable PATH= "c:feb\hi\opy"
i want to remove " "(double quotes) in that above variable.

Comment: May I ask why? ... and BTW: `"c:feb\hi\opy"` is not a valid path. You missed one backslash!  ;-)

Comment: @Olaf Where is invalid path? Absence of ``\`` after `c:` just means that path is relative to current directory on drive `C`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Do you think the OP meant this? ;-)

Comment: @Olaf *Do you think the OP meant this?* Does validity of path depend of that?

Comment: @PetSerAl OK, so I'd like to change my question to: "Are you sure you like to use a relative path or is it a typo?"  ;-)  OK?

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, I am missing your point. Maybe OP have a typo, maybe OP want to use relative path. Does it change anything in OP question? Does quotes removing depend on path to be absolute or not?

Comment: @PetSerAl My actual question was "why". The rest was just for the OP to notice if there is a possible typo in his code. What's your problem with that?

Comment: @Olaf Nothing wrong in pointing possible typo, but your statement exactly as written (`"c:feb\hi\opy"` is not a valid path.) in not correct. I am just pointing that out.

Comment: i have path but when i pass the path through variable sometimes the "(double quotes are also including at the time facing issue with the path)

Answer (score 2):

Use replace:

```
$var="c:feb\hi\opy" -replace '"', ''
```

Comment: i have A.csv file and format like below:
Filename | 
------------------
aaa.dll    |
bbb.dll    |
ccc.dll     |

file name is header
and i have few dll named as aaa.dll,bbb.dll,ccc.dll,ddd.dll,hhh.dll

now i want to move files which are listed in the above A.csv file to destination location.